# 301 redirects - replace a section of the URL

Tags: regex, woocommerce, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm re-working a Woocommerce store, and I need to set up redirects that will send the old URLs, which include category names, to the new URLs, which won't.

**EDIT**: Both the old and new URLs *will* contain `product/` and the old URL may or may not have a trailing slash.

An example would be:

**Old URL**: `myshop.co.uk/product/category-name/sub-category-name/product-name`

**New URL**: `myshop.co.uk/product/product-name`

Can anyone tell me what the reg exp would be to achieve this?

Comment: Try `(myshop.co.uk\/\w*)(.+(?=\/[\w-]*$))(\/[\w-]*$)` and replace with `\1\3` [here](https://regex101.com/r/j2TzcI/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that's really helped. However I should have said that the URL will contain '/product/' every time. I've update your expression to `(.*\/product)(.+(?=\/[\w-]*))(\/[\w-]*$)`, which seems to do that job, however if I add a trailing slash to the old URL, the expression doesn't work. Is it possible to ask the expression to search for a trailing slash or nothing?

Comment: Right, try `(.*\/product)(.+(?=\/[\w-\/]+$))(\/[\w-\/]+$)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/j2TzcI/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `(?<=product/)(?:[^/]+/)+(?=[^/]+/?$)` and replace with an empty string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I had to add backslashes before your slashes to get this to work, but it does indeed work. Is it possible for this expression to check for a trailing slash at the end of the URL?

Comment: Actually, I just checked this again and realised that it only works for exactly two sub pages between "product" and "product-name". That won't quite work for me as there may be more.

Comment: Depending on the tool you use a backslash may indeed be required before the forward slashes. I just updated my answer to account for an optional trailing slash.

Comment: I see. I just updated my answer so that there can be any number of categories between `product/` and the product name.